# Fastlane TestFlight Builds

Tags: ios, build, testflight, fastlane

I've been working to figure out a good solution to pushing daily TestFlight builds to internal testers for our iOS application.  Since these would be pushed daily, I do not want to use existing fastlane actions that generate a commit each time.  What I would like to do is set the build of the app based on an environment variable (a build number generated by Jenkins).

This way, I would just export a build number from the jenkins job and use that to increment the build for the TestFlight upload.

After that I was planning on running this as a daily job.

Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 3):

[Jenkins already exports environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) that you can use in your script.

You are not forced to do a commit everytime, you could simply checkout the latest code, and do something like:

```
lane :testflight_without_commit do 
  increment_build_number(build_number: ENV['BUILD_NUMBER'])
  gym
  pilot
end
```

This will locally set the build number to your jenkin's job build number, and compile an archive with the local changes. Don't commit, don't push, and you should be fine.